# Restoring logical volumes to their original sizes after running lvreduce and screwing things up in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, centos7, xfs

Should have read more on the subject before attempting this, but now I am much more informed... screwing things up tends to do that. Only learned of the shortcomings of `xfs` after the fact.

The OS was apparently installed with the default partitions and type, so there is (was) the following:

```
/dev/mapper/cl-root 50G xfs
/dev/mapper/cl-home 50G xfs
```

The `cl-root` was at 100% so thought I'd steal the space from `cl-home` since it wasn't really being used.

Did the following:

```
lvresize --size 10GB /dev/mapper/cl-home
lvresize --size 89GB /dev/mapper/cl-root
```

Both were successful and the changes are reflected in `lvdisplay` for each volume; however `df -h` was still showing them as the same size.

Decided to reboot which is where the screw up became apparent because it went into emergency mode due to `/home` not mounting properly. As a work around I modified `/etc/fstab` so that it was `nofail` for the `/dev/mapper/cl-home` which allowed me to boot up normally, although it did remake the `/home` directory.

I look at `df -h` and it is not showing `/dev/mapper/cl-home` and the filesystem is still showing the same size for `/dev/mapper/cl-root`. `lvdisplay` shows the adjust drive sizes.

Try to `mount /home` and get: `mount: /dev/mapper/cl-home: can't read superblock`.

From what I understand the process of reducing or increasing the size of a file system is two part: 1) modifying the logical volume and then 2) modifying the file system. I am under the impression I have already done 1) and just need to do 2).

Try:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/cl-home 10G

resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/cl-home
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Try:

```
xfs_repair /dev/mapper/cl-home

Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
error reading superblock 1 -- seek to offset 13315866624 failed
couldn't verify primary superblock - attempted to perform I/O beyond EOF !!!

attempting to find secondary superblock...
...Sorry, could not find valid secondary superblock
Exiting now.
```

Ok, well I guess I'll try to expand the `/root` then and basically get the same errors.

So at this point I just want to put it back the way it was.

```
lvresize --size 50G /dev/mapper/cl-root

WARNING: Reducing active and open logical volume to 50.00 GiB.
THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)

Do you really want to reduce cl/root? [y/n]:
```

Not sure I want to do that on this filesystem.

It doesn't seem I can increase the `/dev/mapper/cl-home` without decrease `cl-root` first.

So from where I stand I am kind of stuck. Everything is running fine at this point though, so I guess I could just leave it.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Anyway, was using these links as guides.

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/increase_the_size_of_an_lvm_logical_volume.html

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/increase_the_size_of_an_ext2_ext3_or_ext4_filesystem.html

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reduce_the_size_of_an_ext2_ext3_or_ext4_filesystem.html

Someone with a similar issue which leads me to believe that I should just leave it alone.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/home-partition-doesn%27t-mount-after-resizing-using-lvreduce-can%27t-read-superblock-4175593319/

Comment: You cannot shrink an XFS filesystem except by backup/format/restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XFS filesystems can only be grown, they cannot be shrunk.

If your setup is likely to need filesystems to be shrunk use EXT4 instead.

Also - when using `lvresize`, ensure you also use the `-r` / `--resizefs` option, else you WILL mess up your filesystems, perhaps irretrievably.  While I personally haven't tested it on reducing an xfs filesystem, I would expect it to report an error and not resize anything (as the xfs resize tool would be aware it cannot shrink a filesystem).